# Access application deployed in windows docker container from other machine

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I installed **Docker Desktop for Windows** in my Windows 10 computer, and created a `hyper-v` virtual machine named ***MobyLinuxVM***. I deployed a `mongodb` to a new container, and mapped the port to **MobyLinuxVM 27017 port**. The MobyLinuxVM virtual machine ip is `10.0.75.2`, and the host win10 machine ip is 192.168.1.10. The MobyLinuxVM use a **internal network** type hyper-v virtual switch named DockerNAT, it is the default switch for the ***MobyLinuxVM***.

Now I can access the Mongo database from the host win10 machine. But how can I access the mongo database from other machine? I try to change the MobyLinuxVM machine network adapter to another external network type virtual switch, but I cannot get the MobyLinuxVM virtual machine IP, and I try to log in the virtual machine by SSH, but didn't konw the user name and password.

So how to access the database deployed in a windows docker container from other machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your virtual machine will get its own ip address only if you will use bridged network.Once you your hyper-v gets ip address , you will be able to access it from other machine.Issue is not with docker but network adapter of hyper-v.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Girdhar! It seems I misunderstanded the docker for windows port map. When I run docker with parameter *-p Port1:Port2*, it seems docker for windows do something more than I understanded, the Port1 represent the port on my host win10 machine.  Because some app in my host machine has use the same port, and the firewall reason, I access the container app always failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a command like "docker run -p port1:port2 mongodb" then you should have an access to this service using host of machine where docker engine was run: mongodb://your_windows_machine_host:port2
This case works for me and I havn't done special settings to access mongo in container.